# Datatable presubmit 2 fileds

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have two fields to send in the dataTable submit "PRICE" and "INSTALLMENT PRICE" (INSPRICE)

Before i sent i need to do a validation

```
editor.on('preSubmit', function (e, o, action) {
            if (action !== 'remove') {

                if (o.data.PRICE != "" && (o.data.INSPRICE == "0" || o.data.INSPRICE == "")) {

                    if (parseInt(o.data.PRICE.replace(".", "").replace(",", ".")) < parseInt(o.data.MINPRICE) || parseInt(o.data.PRICE.replace(".", "").replace(",", ".")) > parseInt(o.data.MAXPRICE)) {
                        swal({
                            title: "PRICE!",
                            text: "PRICE IS TOO LOW",
                            type: "warning"
                        });
                        return true;
                    }


                }

                if (o.data.INSPRICE!= "0") {

                    if (parseInt(o.data.INSPRICE.replace(".", "").replace(",", ".")) < parseInt(o.data.MINPRICE) || parseInt(o.data.INSPRICE.replace(".", "").replace(",", ".")) > parseInt(o.data.MAXPRICE)) {

                        swal({
                            title: "Preço!",
                            text: "INSPRICE IS TOO LOW",
                            type: "warning"
                        });
                        return true;
                    }


                }
            };
        });
```

i need to validate the fields separately

that way how i'm doing when i send the price i have the validation for price and insprice

same happens with INSPRICE

Comment: or how can i know what's field were clicked to edit

Answer (score 1):

i solved using this

```
$('#table').on('click', 'tbody td', function (e) {
            if ($(this).index() === 5) {
                indiceEditor = $(this).index();
                editor.inline(this, ['PRICE'], {
                    submitOnBlur: true
                });
            }

            $('#DTE_Field_INSPRICE').mask("#.##0,00", { reverse: true });
            if ($(this).index() === 6) {
                indiceEditor = $(this).index();
                editor.inline(this, ['INSPRICE'], {
                    submitOnBlur: true
                });
            }
        });
```

i'm using variable indiceEditor to know wich field i will update for time